# How to trigger reload on a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, flutter-hive

I am new to flutter and working on a visualisation of a member db as app.

My App has a side navigation (home_drawer) with contains a sync button to force update the db data. The data gets stored in app (hive). So when I press the sync button a method in my db-sync.service gets called and updates the data in storage.

Currently, when I am on my member list site and open the sidebar to sync the data the site did not reload and show the new data. I need to switch the site to force a reload of the member list.

**member-list site**

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  setState(() {
    member = Hive.box<Mitglied>('members').values.toList().cast<Member>();
  });
}
```

The sync-button and db-sync.service code is a bit to long to show. But at the end I only store/update new members in hive  `memberBox.put(memberId, member);`

So it is obvious, that there is no reload at the moment and the `setState()` in the initState is useless. But I don't know what's the right way to do it. I could try a kind of event messaging through the app, but I think there is a much better way and you can tell me how.

Comment: you can reassign the member

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i am not saure what you mean, can you show me a example or a reference were I can look it up?

Comment: You like update `member` on tap event ?

Answer (score 1):

Listen to changes to rebuild instead of trying to figure out how and when to reload. Something like this:

```
ValueListenableBuilder<Box>(
  valueListenable: Hive.box('members').listenable(),
  builder: (context, box, widget) {
...
  },
),
```

See [Hive in Flutter](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/hive_in_flutter) for details.

Comment: This did not work for me... Don't know why. But the listenable lead me to a working solution. Thank you :D memberBox.listenable().addListener(() {...});

Comment: @JanneckLange If you have already found a solution, don't forget to post it as an answer! And [accept](/help/accepted-answer) it.